# Remove login identification Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: command-line, login, configuration, 21.10

I have a special application requiring a "straight" system load, without asking for login credentials. The same process is possible under Windows 10.

Basically, I want to automatically login, without being asked for user id and password, even if my account is admin. I have tried to enable Automatic login through the Configuration -> Users interface, but could not find the recommended lock icon.
As I have a Kubuntu Plasma on top of Ubuntu 21.10, I've also tried to enable Automatic login usind the Simple Desktop Display Manager. Didn' work either.

As my question seemed to confuse, here is straight: how can I enable Automatic login from the command line?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en?

Comment: @Bodo: I don't have any lock on window's up right corner, that's why I've asked the question. I don't know if it matters that I run Kubuntu on top. Otherwise, which would be more useful for me later, could this be enabled in terminal?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, that will be one of the next features, which is done through the start-up config. But I imagine that I have first to get rid of the login window, by setting autologin.

Comment: @GingerOpariti Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly do you want to achieve? Adding an example might help. I do not understand your [reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371517/remove-login-identification-ubuntu-21-10?noredirect=1#comment2358703_1371517).

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for taking your time with my issue, I have reached my competence limits :-) ...

Comment: A **graphical** application that runs at boot without any login is usually called a **kiosk**.  A **headless** application that runs at boot without any login is usually called a **service**. How to do either is well-documented. Neither require automatic login. Your solution of "no login" seems to me misdirected. If you want something different from a kiosk or a service, then please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1371517/edit) to describe it -- your end goal is not clear, so it's hard to provide useful help.

Comment: @user535733: Thank you

Comment: You do not have any unlock button in the right corner of the "Users" dialog? That would suggest you are using an account that does not have administrative ("sudo") permissions.

Comment: @vanadium: I am in the User dialog window and I am identified as 'administrator'. The only action allowed is Change password'. What I'm looking for is to disable the login window for any account type (in fact, I want to avoid any credentials entry), so that system loads directly to the KDE Plasma desktop screen. Again, the same as Windows 10 allows.

Comment: In stock Ubuntu, there normally is the "Unlock" button, that when used, unlocks the other settings.

Comment: @vanadium: I have installed from Ubuntu downloads the latest 21.10 version, no Unlock button. Regarding my installed 21.10 I have also posted a note that on the welcome screen I have the label 21.04 with the Indri in the background. These might be version bugs ...

Comment: That is possible. I also have 21.10, however it is an upgraded version in my case.